# How to assign the sprite to material's texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

How to add sprite to player material with script. I have a shop menu of player and when a like to select one sprite i like to add to player material but I don't know how to do this. I have my code but just this I don't know how to add. This is my code I made like this but don't work can someone tell me how to add playerSprite to playermaterial. this code: **GameManager.Instance.playerMaterial = GameManager.Instance.playerSprite[index];**

Answer (score 0):

Well your code should throw you an error: `GameManager.Instance.playerMaterial = GameManager.Instance.playerSprite[index];` means you're trying to provide a [Sprite](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.html) to a [Material](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.html).

In your situation you have 2 options:

- convert the Sprite to a [Texture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture.html) at runtime and then apply it to `playerMaterial.mainTexture` (you can use `Sprite.texture` I think)
- depending on the usage of your Sprites (if you don't use them as Sprites as well), you can also change your Sprites import settings to textures and declare the array as a Textures one so (this will avoid the runtime conversion)

*Hope this helps,*